# Startup value does not set selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've made a simple angular.js example which shows my problem: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/maluramichael/d3jf7ueq/)

I want to set the start value of the select element to a specific value.

```
    <select name="i" id="i" ng-model="selectedItem">
        <option ng-repeat="i in items" value="{{i}}">{{i}}</option>
    </select>
```

The options and the select element get rendered perfectly. But, like in the example, when i set the value in my controller to 6, the selected value on the page is still the first element.

```
scope.selectedItem = 6;
```

There are 2 simple buttons which just change the selected value. When you press them the selection change without problems.

EDIT: i updated the jsfiddle and removed unused code and renamed code to make things a bit more clear

EDIT2: I missed to ask if it is possible to fix the second select element too? The different is that this array contains objects instead of numbers.

```
    <select name="o" id="o" ng-model="selectedItem">
        <option ng-repeat="o in objects" ng-value="{{o.ID}}">{{o.Text}}</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: The scope variable is `$scope`, not `scope`.

Comment: @JimCote i renamed the dependency

Comment: Your fiddle uses `scope` all throughout the controller.

Comment: Your `<div>Test {{selectedItem}}</div>` use in out of controller

Comment: The best pratice to use select and options with AngularJS is using ng-options. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: For the second select you want ngModel to bind to ID property of the objects?

Comment: @dfsq Yes thats right.

Comment: set the selectedItem in $timeout.
`$timeout(function () { $scope.selectedItem = 6 })`

Comment: See updated answer with the second selectbox fixed too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `ngRepeat` to render option elements, it's not supposed to work properly with select and options. Use [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) which will work as expected with `ngModel`:

```
<select name="i" id="i" 
        ng-model="selectedItem"
        ng-options="i for i in items">
</select>
```

For the second selectbox which has ngModel bound to ID property of the objects in array, it will be:

```
<select name="o" id="o" 
        ng-model="selectedItem" 
        ng-options="obj.ID as obj.Text for obj in objects">
</select>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/d3jf7ueq/9/

Comment: Thanks. This works perfect. At the moment i dunno why but i'll read the ngOptions documentation.